# Intellij - Event log font

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to change the font of Intellij IDEA "Event log" panel content font? I am using Community Edition 2019.1.

I have search in Google and here, but Color Schema does not contain this configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA is using the font from the IDE **Appearance** settings in the **Event Log** tool window:

[image: Appearance font]

**Line spacing** is taken from the **Console Font** settings:

[image: line spacing]

There is no separate font setting for the **Event Log**.

Comment: Correct. Inconvenient, because I have to change all the UI font just for one panel.... unlike Console font which is independent. At last Microsoft Yahei UI was my choice.